# Using Google Maps API in Web Application

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Basically all I want to do for now is just allow someone to enter an address and have it save the data in my database and display it on a Google map. Then when other people come to it, they can view the "pins" that other people have placed. Do I do all of the interaction with Google Maps using JavaScript? PHP?

I've done some searching and it isn't all that clear to me. Just looking for guidance on how to get started so I don't end up going back and changing things later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Maps is a client-side technology so you'll be using JavaScript. See [this guide](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/introduction.html) for getting started.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help! That should be all I needed to get going. Can't believe I missed that in there, I was looking in the same site haha

Comment: Yep, it's a good guide and it has a link to the API documentation which, as these things go, is pretty nicely written and easy to follow. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of tutorials on the web about the subject.

It is actually quite simple once you understand the API.

To get the pin's etc you can store them with php in MySQL and then to show the map just translate into values the API can understand.

Here is a good tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax